# Ошибка "thread 1: fatal error: index out of range" + неправильная реализация удаления ячейки свайпом

Tags: ios, swift

Расширение состоит из трех функций.

В первой функции возвращаю сумму количества отображаемых ячеек. 
`contactsDataSource.numberOfContacts()` связан с массивом внутри программы.
`contacts.count` связан с массивом, который грузится с сервера.

**Проблема**: Во второй функции возвращаются сами ячейки этих массивов. Именно здесь возникает ошибка, она приведена в коде под комментарием. Ошибка связана с неправильным индексом.

Код работает правильно, если отображать ячейки этих двух массивом раздельно, но при использовании вместе я получаю эту ошибку.

В третей функции реализован свайп удаления ячейки. Здесь также, если использовать раздельно удаление ячеек. То удаление происходит верно. Но если использовать все вместе, у меня этот способ не работает.

**Вопрос**: Как можно сделать, чтобы он удалял правильно ячейки при использовании вместе?

```swift
extension ContactsViewController {
  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let a = contactsDataSource.numberOfContacts()
    let b = contacts.count
    return (a + b)
  }
  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ContactCell", for: indexPath) as! ContactsCell
    cell.contact = contactsDataSource.contact(at: indexPath)
    cell.setup(with: contacts[indexPath.row]) //Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range
    return cell
  }
  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
      if (editingStyle == .delete) {
        contactsDataSource.contacts.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        contacts.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
        tableView.endUpdates()
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У Вас что-то неправильно с организацией данных. Ключевая проблема, которая бросается в глаза:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let a = contactsDataSource.numberOfContacts()
    let b = contacts.count
    return (a + b) 
    // Вы здесь суммируете количество контактов
}
// А здесь берете данные из двух массивов по одному и тому же индексу
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ContactCell", for: indexPath) as! ContactsCell
    cell.contact = contactsDataSource.contact(at: indexPath)
    cell.setup(with: contacts[indexPath.row]) //Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range
    return cell
}
```

Здесь и без удаления должны быть проблемы когда оба массива не пусты.

Возможно, лучше будет разделить таблицу на секции и отображать данные из разных массивов в разных секциях?

Comment: Да, думаю вы правы. Но как лучше это сделать? У меня динамическая таблица, и я могу добавить только еще одни ячейки, но я не могу добавить дополнительную секцию, это доступно только для статических ячеек. Я создал дополнительную ячейку и пытаюсь разделить данные, но к сожалению мне не хватает опыта сделать это правильно.

Comment: @xzinx в динамической таблице также можно добавлять секции. Метод dataSource numberOfSections https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdatasource/1614860-numberofsections

Comment: @xzinx ну и примеры реализации уже ищите по этим данным. К примеру, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42552611/populating-tableview-with-multiple-sections-and-multiple-dictionary-in-an-array

Comment: Ваш ссылка, где описан пример реализации - мне очень помог. Спасибо! Моя проблема решена.

Answer (score 0):

Можно проверить в начале функции `override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath:)`, что число элементов массива не меньше, чем число вызываемого индекса, например, так:

```
guard contacts.count > indexPath.row else { return UITableViewCell() }
```

Comment: При наличии данных в массиве, который внутри программы, и отсутствии данных на сервере, то в итоге таблица пуста. Но при наличии данных с сервера программа теперь падает с ошибкой "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value" на том моменте, где у меня прописан reloadData():
private var contacts = [ContactAPI]() {
      didSet {
          tableViewContacts.reloadData()
      }
  }